# Propagating the AutoScaleDimensions property

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, scale, compact-framework

.NET CF 3.5

How can I scale everything on my form ?

If I do this

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(120F, 120F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
```

then the controls directly added on the form are properly repositioned BUT  their size is not properly updated !

So how should I propagate the scaling factor to each sub-control ?

Answer (score -1):

if you set that code on the InitializeComponent method it works or you can overrides the AutoScaleDimensions property.

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(120F, 120F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
```

Comment: How is this doing anything different from the code in the question?